# Make an inner div take up 100% of an outer responsive div (Floating Issues)

Tags: html, css

This is sort of hard to explain so I made a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8wujkpqb/

I have a right floating div with a max-width set. I need the div inside of that to take up 100% of the max-width so the content can be left-aligned to the content in the div below.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="mainleft">
    <div class="outer-red">
        <div class="first">
            I need this<br/> pushed to the left<br/> to align with the<br/> lower text but still<br/> be in a "max-width"<br/> container floating right.
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="outer-gray">
        <div class="second">
            this is fine because there is enough content to take up the max-width. this is fine because there is enough content to take up the max-width. this is fine because there is enough content to take up the max-width
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainright">
    <div class="right-content">
        content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
width: 100%;
}

.mainleft {
width: 50%;
float: left;
}

.mainright {
width: 50%;
float: left;
}

.outer-red {
width:100%;
background: red;
padding: 40px;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.outer-gray {
width:100%;
background: gray;
padding: 40px;
box-sizing:border-box;
}


.first {
float: right;
max-width:250px;
clear:both;
}

.second {
float: right;
max-width:250px;
}

.right-content {
width:100%;
background: blue;
padding: 40px;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8wujkpqb/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @J4G the .container is the full site width. So 50% of full browser window is the red and gray and 50% is the blue. The max-width divs floating right keep the content in line with the rest of the page's centered content divs. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another div into your "first" container that possesses the `max-width` and let the parent be the size that is necessary to align the inner container left. Like so

```
.first {
    float: right;
    max-width: 100%;
    clear:both;
    width: 200px
}

.inner {
    max-width: 200px
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8wujkpqb/1/

Comment: Looks like I don't even need to add .inner as long as I fix max-width: 100% and width: 200px?